# Multiple select2 elements on one page not working

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-select2

I want to have multiple select2 on one page. The app has several posts and each post will have a select element. I am hiding the element until the user clicks on a button which then shows select. The problem is that only one select2 works.

Here's my HTML:

```
<button onclick="change_tags({{ file.id }})" class="btn btn-info btn-sm change-tags-btn">Change Tags</button>

     <select class="custom-select js-example-basic-multiple change-tags-select form-control " id="change-tags" name="usertags1" multiple="multiple">
      {% for tag in userTags %}
         <option value="{{ tag }}" id="{{ tag }}" data-id="{{ tag.color }}" class="options">{{ tag }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
   </select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.change-tags-btn').click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#change-tags').select2()
            },1000);
        });
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, javascript will just target the first one found.

Comment: Not even with same class name too. Only two of elements work. Others none.